# Facebook: "user is not allowed to see the application" is received when end user tries to login to my facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app which was basically created for subscribing page for real time change notification.

Ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks 
https://www.facebook.com/marketingdevelopers/videos/883648801749520/

I have also make it public from the app's "App Review" tab. The user who created that app can successfully logins and the real time changes notification is working as expected.

But, when end user tries to login to that app, it does not allow. It shows following message

*user is not allowed to see the application*

Is there anything missing?

**Update** (Jun 17): Added the javascript code that I used in the aspx page.
User open that page in browser. The page just contains a login to facebook button. When it is click, it opens a pop window to login to Facebook.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
      appId: '145141412569340',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
  });  };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    function subscribeApp(page_id, page_name, access_token) {

        console.log('Subscribing page to app! ' + page_name);
        FB.api('/' + page_id + '/subscribed_apps',
            'post',
            {'access_token': access_token},
            function (response) {
                console.log('Successfully subscribed page name: ' + page_name +  ' , pageId: ' + page_id + ', success: ' , response);
            });

    }

    // Only works after `FB.init` is called
    function myFacebookLogin() {
        FB.login(function (response) {
            //alert('Successfully loggined : ' + response);
            console.log('Successfully loggined : ' + response.status, response);
            FB.api('me/accounts', function (response) {
                console.log('Successfully retrived pages ', response);
                var pages = response.data;
                var ul = document.getElementById('list');
                for (var i = 0, len = pages.length; i < len; i++) {
                    var page = pages[i];
                    var li = document.createElement('li');
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = "#";
                    a.innerHTML = page.name;
                    a.onclick = subscribeApp.bind(this, page.id,page.name, page.access_token);
                    li.appendChild(a);
                    ul.appendChild(li);

                }
            });
        }, { scope: 'manage_pages,email,public_profile,read_page_mailboxes,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_events,user_friends,user_hometown,user_location,user_posts,user_relationship_details,user_relationships,user_religion_politics,user_website,user_work_history,user_likes' });
    }
```

Comment: How is the user trying to login? (Which URL did they call to get to the point where they can login from.) Which app platforms do you have your app configured for?

Comment: I have a facebook app of Webhook type. I have just added a "Facebook convas" platform in my app.
I have updated the question to include the JavaScript code. Please see the Update (Jun 17) section.

Comment: It looks like when adding "Website" platform in the app the issue is resolved. Thanks for providing the hints.
Now, I can grab the app scoped user id and the accessToken after user login to my app from the browser.

But when I tried to fetch the Posts of that user using the query in the Graph API explorer, I got the following error 

**The field 'feed' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'user_posts' permission.**

I have already defined "user_posts" permission in the "scope" in the JavaScript code.

Comment: Of course users can’t login, if you configure your app for webhooks _only_. / _“I have already defined "user_posts" permission in the "scope" in the JavaScript code”_ – but did the user actually grant the permission to your app?

Comment: When user logins to my app, it first opens a window to enter user name and password. After entering values and click login, no other window opens. Is something missing in my app?

The purpose of my app is to grab user's profile, page, posts and also subscribe for real time change. Currently, I have just added the Webhook in the app. Do I need to add other product in my app?

Comment: Try removing the app from your settings in Facebook, and then login again. And yes, you will have to configure the website platform and app the product Facebook Login (if not already the case.)